# ASTMatcher for class instance with Initialization and the member function call

Tags: clang-ast-matchers

I'm having difficulty getting the ASTMatcher for the following entities. The first one is the instance of a class.

```
Vec v1(1.0,1.0,1.0);
Vec v2(2.0,2.0,2.0);
```

Ideally, I can have a matcher that can match both instances.

The second is to capture the call of a member function `vec_add` and its implicit argument`v1` and explicit argument`v2`.

```
Vec v3 = v1.vec_add(v1);
Vec v4 = v1.vec_add(v2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution for the first kind:

```
declStmt(containsDeclaration(0, varDecl(hasInitializer(cxxConstructExpr(argumentCountIs(3))))))
```

The solution to the second kind is

```
callExpr(callee(namedDecl(hasName("vec_add"))))
```

Now I kinda know how to think about the design now. 
Stay tuned for my blog on this!